# Squashed spheres in general dimension

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, topology

The point of this question is to help me find references regarding squashed spheres in general dimension. I am interested in the general theory of squashing for arbitrary dimension. All of the references or applications to squashing that I've seen thus far refer to specific dimensions, such as 3 or 7, which are rather exceptional from a Mathematical point of view. I am not sure if the formalism developed in these dimensions can be straightforwardly applied to any dimension, or if the situation is more complicated.

This is purely a mathematical subject, but it has applications in gravity and string theory.

Note: for those who don't know, squashing is a technical term, and not a heuristic one. Squashing is a special type of deformation that preserves topology and the coset structure of the manifold. For example in 3 dimensions the sphere has SO(4) isometry group, but squashing reduces it to SU(2).

Comment: *What* exactly would you want to learn about squashed spheres?

Comment: I want to know if spheres can be squashed in any dimension, and how they may be squashed.

Comment: That's still not very clear to me: Do you mean to ask if ellipsoids exist in arbitrary dimension? Isn't that kind of clear? Or do you mean something else by "squashed sphere"?

Comment: Squashing here is a technical term. Ellipsoids are not squashed spheres, for example, squashed spheres only exist in dimensions $\gt 3$. Squashing is a special type of deformation that preserves topology and the coset structure. For example in 3 dimensions the sphere has SO(4) isometry group, but squashing reduces it to SU(2) $\simeq$ SO(3).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I guess it'd be nice if you could find a source to link to, so others don't have to go through the confusion about the meaning of "squashed spheres" (the link you have right now is not very good, because the first few results are about ellipsoids).

Comment: Oh, I think that link was included by Qmechanic, let me add a more relevant one.

Comment: This is a purely mathematical question. Why not use math.stackexchange instead?

Comment: As a physicist, all applications of squashing that I've seen occurred in physics contexts, and I'm not sure the language the physicists used would be the same as the mathematicians. May I please request that if you do not have anything to say regarding squashing, you leave this question alone? I'm just looking for references.

Comment: This still does not contain any link to a source where your terminology is explained.

Comment: I don't understand this objection. If the reader does not know what squashing is, then I do not think they'll be able to point me to a good general reference. If I was posting a question on Yang-Mills, would I need to include a link to a group theory textbook?